# check if database was updated then deleting file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

I have written a service that reads XML files from a directory creates objects out of the data and passes the data into the database. I want to check if the database was updated with each game object and if it was updated correctly delete the file if it wasn't added correctly for any reason I want to move the file to an error folder for later processing.

```
[WebMethod] 
public void RunService() 
{ 
    //Call XML loader to get collection of XML documents  
    foreach (GamePlay value in XMLLoader.Start()) 
    { 
        value.addNewGamePlay(); 
    } 
    //call inject data method for each collection 
}
```

This XMLLoader class returns the array of GamePlay objects:

```
public static Array Start() 
{ 
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\bradleya\Desktop\XML\"); 
   List<GamePlay> gameObj = new List<GamePlay>();  

   foreach (string value in filePaths) 
   { 
      XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument(); 
      xd.Load(value); 
      XmlNode documentNode = xd.SelectSingleNode("/GamePlayData/GamePlay"); 

      GamePlay newGame = new GamePlay(); 
      newGame.setType(Convert.ToString(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setGamePlayID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GamePlayID").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setParticipantID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("ParticipantID").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setGameVersionID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameVersionID").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setGameID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameID").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setGameScenarioID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameScenarioID").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setStartDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("Start").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setEndDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("End").InnerText)); 
      newGame.setSuccess(Convert.ToBoolean(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("Success").InnerText)); 

      gameObj.Add(new GamePlay); 
   } 

   return gameObj.ToArray(); 
}
```

This method is fired in the object class that passes the object variable to the data access layer:

```
public void addNewGamePlay() 
{ 
    // dataaccess method call to add GamePlay 
    // (from the DB) is then set for the object 
    DataAccessConn.createNewGamePlay(this.ParticipantID, this.GameVersionID, this.GameID, this.GameScenarioID, this.StartDateTime, this.EndDateTime, this.success); 
}
```

Finally the data is passed into the database via the data access layer method here:

```
public static void createNewGamePlay(int ParticipantID, int GameVersionID,int GameID,int GameSenarioID,DateTime Start,DateTime End,Boolean success) 
{ 
   SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(); 
   oConn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SNICKERS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VervePhaseOne;Integrated Security=True"; 

   oConn.Open(); 

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
   cmd.Connection = oConn; 
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
   cmd.CommandText = "addGamePlay"; 

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParticipantID", SqlDbType.Int)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@ParticipantID"].Value = ParticipantID; 
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameVersionID", SqlDbType.Int)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@GameVersionID"].Value = GameVersionID; 
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameID", SqlDbType.Int)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@GameID"].Value = GameID; 
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameScenarioID", SqlDbType.Int)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@GameScenarioID"].Value = GameSenarioID; 
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@Start"].Value = DateTime.Now; 
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@End"].Value = DateTime.Now; 
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@success", SqlDbType.Bit)); 
   cmd.Parameters["@success"].Value = success; 

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

The XML file I'm trying to pass is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <GamePlayData> 
      <GamePlay> 
        <type>add</type> 
        <GamePlayID>1</GamePlayID> 
        <ParticipantID>1</ParticipantID> 
        <GameVersionID>1</GameVersionID> 
        <GameID>1</GameID> 
        <GameScenarioID>1</GameScenarioID> 
        <Start>22/01/2012 23:59:59</Start>  
        <End>22/01/2012 23:59:59</End>  
        <Success>False</Success>  
      </GamePlay> 
    </GamePlayData>
```

The addGamePlay store procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addGamePlay] 
@ParticipantID int, 
@GameVersionID int, 
@GameID int, 
@GameScenarioID int, 
@Start dateTime, 
@End dateTime, 
@Success varchar(10) 
AS 
INSERT INTO GamePlay(ParticipantID,GameVersionID,GameID,GameScenarioID,StartDateTime,EndDateTime,Success) 
VALUES (@ParticipantID,@GameVersionID,@GameID,@GameScenarioID,@Start,@End,@Success) 
return @@identity
```

To clarify my question, I want to add a form of validation to check if the file was read correctly and the data was passed into the database correctly before I either delete the file from the directory or move it to an error folder. I was thinking about creating a variable in the object class called "rootFile" so I can easily delete it and add a test into the Run service method if it passes the test delete else if remove but I am not sure of the syntax or if this is the best way. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion from me count the no. of records present in the xml file and when you insert the records in a table it also returns no. of rows affected. If both the numbers are equal then the database is updated correctly otherwise some error occured, hope you understand it.

Comment: good suggestion, thanks. Only issue is it gets data from a number of XML files in a directory so I would need to pin point the XML file that errored. I just need to find a way to check in the foreach loop if the update was successful

Comment: are you inserting the data in a single step or one by one read xml and insert into the table ? if you are reading and inserting one xml at a time then count the records in xml and no.of rows affected retrun from the sp and checked they are equal if not the name of that file in memory( viewstate,session ). What problem you are facing now ?